# Toggle item specific data property to show/hide text Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

Please take a look at my snippet. I am trying to toggle the viewMore data property only when its corresponding view all/view less button is clicked.

Each item needs to have its own toggle button, but i only want to toggle the "active" item i am clicking on.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    viewMore: false,
    arrayOfData: [{
        description: 'ITEM 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
      {
        description: 'ITEM 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
      {
        description: 'ITEM 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    showItemModifiers: function() {
      this.viewMore = !this.viewMore;
    }
  },
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.selectedModifiersList {
  max-height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.selectedModifiersList.viewMore {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in arrayOfData">
    <div class="selectedModifiersList" :class="{'viewMore':viewMore}">
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>

    <button @click="showItemModifiers">
    <span v-if="viewMore">View Less</span>
    <span v-else >View All</span>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably your best bet is to make a view-more component. That way each one can keep track of its own state. Or you could add a state variable to each item in `arrayOfData` and have the toggle operate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your array of data, you can make a component that handles the state for each item individually.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    arrayOfData: [{
        description: 'ITEM 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
      {
        description: 'ITEM 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
      {
        description: 'ITEM 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
    ],
  },
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    viewMore: {
      template: '#view-more-template',
      props: ['item'],
      data() {
        return {
          expand: false
        };
      },
      methods: {
        toggle() {
          this.expand = !this.expand; 
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.selectedModifiersList {
  max-height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.selectedModifiersList.viewMore {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <view-more v-for="item in arrayOfData" :item="item"></view-more>
</div>

<template id="view-more-template">
  <div>
    <div class="selectedModifiersList" :class="{'viewMore':expand}">
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>

    <button @click="toggle">
      <span v-if="expand">View Less</span>
      <span v-else >View All</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to have viewMore for each data.
When switching, only viewMore in the data is switched.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    arrayOfData: [{
        viewMore: false,
        description: 'ITEM 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
      {
        viewMore: false,
        description: 'ITEM 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
      {
        viewMore: false,
        description: 'ITEM 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.',
      },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    showItemModifiers: function(item) {
      item.viewMore = !item.viewMore;
    }
  },
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.selectedModifiersList {
  max-height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.selectedModifiersList.viewMore {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in arrayOfData">
    <div class="selectedModifiersList" :class="{'viewMore':item.viewMore}">
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>

    <button @click="showItemModifiers(item)">
    <span v-if="item.viewMore">View Less</span>
    <span v-else >View All</span>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. i understand now! i just got confused because my array of data was hooked up with a bunch of chained models.